# How to implement NSCoding for Properties and ivars automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nscoding

I am trying to save a lot of objects to a file and retrieve them for later use.

Previously, I used [these macros](http://stablekernel.com/blog/speeding-up-nscoding-with-macros/) - it felt tedious though.

Then I discovered [Autocoding](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AutoCoding), which is awesome in its own way but it can't encode/decode instance variables.

I am in need of automating the whole process of encoding/decoding since my app is still under development and it's tedious to write encode/decode implementation for every ivar.

Comment: Can you use properties instead of ivars?

Comment: Ya I can, but I cant force all my team mates to do so. Hope you understand my situation.

Comment: Do you have a solution? @AaronBrager

Comment: Doing things like this makes upgrading difficult.  If your class implementation changes, you may have to write and maintain painful serialization upgrade methods.

Comment: That being said, I answered a similar question a little while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054122/using-nscoder-and-nskeyedarchiver-with-runtime-reflection-to-deep-copy-a-custom/28054556#28054556

Comment: @riyaz You could try convincing them, or yelling at them, or reverting their commits that use ivars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just overide the +codableProperties method and return the names of the ivars. It's not as nice as detecting them automatically, but nicer than writing the NSCoding logic manually.

Comment: This might be the best solution; there are some real pitfalls with a completely automatic approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of ivars associated with a class from the Objective-C runtime  -- see the [class_copyIvarList](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_copyIvarList) function. Likewise, you can get the value of an ivar for a specific object using [object_getIvar](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/object_getIvar) and set it with [object_setIvar](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/object_setIvar). These seem like the main tools you'd need to automatically encode an object's ivars.

One place you'll need to be careful is that you won't want to save both the value for a property and the value for the ivar that backs it. So you'll probably want to compare the list of ivars to the list of properties, and only encode/decode those ivars for which there doesn't seem to be a corresponding property.

Also, it's not always desirable to make every last bit of an object's state persistent, so you should consider providing a way to opt out for specific ivars (which might in the end be just as tedious as opting in). As well, you'll probably need to determine which ivars you even *can* encode, e.g. the usual value types and any types which themselves implement NSCoding.

Comment: [Here's a good sketch of an implementation](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/1488943727/aspect-oriented-programming) (but it doesn't resolve all of Caleb's concerns).

Comment: extending `codableProperties` and and making use of `class_copyIvarList`, `object_getIvar`, `object_setIvar` etc solves my problems.

//it's not always desirable to make every last bit of an object's state persistent, so you should consider providing a way to opt out for specific ivars//
I should have to find a way to solve this problem.
thanks